# AngularJS and PHPMailer email button function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am currently developing an application that allows users to send emails with one click of a button, whether its a singular email to an individual or bulk too all contacts.

I am stuck on how to link AJAX to the singular send button and PHPMailer file.

This is where the button is located as 'Send Single':

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="display">
    <td>{{data.customer_name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.customer_email}}</td>

    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="single_select" class="single_select" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm email_button" ng-click="sendData(data.customer_name)">Send Single</button>
    </td>

    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="showEdit(data)">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="deleteData(data.id)">Delete</button>
    </td>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="formData.customer_name" class="form-control"  /></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="formData.customer_email" class="form-control" /></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td>
         <input type="hidden" ng-model="formData.data.id" />
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="editData()">Save</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
     </td>
</script>
```

I have tried editing what the delete button is doing to allow this to send, but failed.

```
$scope.sendData = function sendData(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to send?"))
    {
        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:"send_mail.php",
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.success = true;
            $scope.successMessage = data.message;
            $scope.fetchData();
        }); 
    }
}
```

This is how the application currently looks, link below:

[Image of current application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A1M1.png)

**EDIT**

The HTML code for the email is sat in the `PHPMailer` file, I do not need it to be processed through a form.

**ORIGINAL WORKING VERSION**

PHP

```
<?php
 $count = 0;
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $count++;
  echo '
  <tr id="index_table">
   <td>'.$row["customer_name"].'</td>
   <td>'.$row["customer_email"].'</td>
   <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="single_select" class="single_select" data-email="'.$row["customer_email"].'" data-name="'.$row["customer_name"].'" />
   </td>
   <td><button type="button" name="email_button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs email_button" id="'.$count.'" data-email="'.$row["customer_email"].'" data-name="'.$row["customer_name"].'" data-action="single">Send Single</button></td>
   </td>
   <td></td>
   <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo escape($row["customer_id"]); ?>"><button type="button" name="delete" id="delete" data-row="row"+count+"" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">DELETE</button></a></td>
  </tr>
  ';
 }
 ?>
```

AJAX (didnt like code block)

> ```
>     $.ajax({
>    url:"send_mail.php",
>    method:"POST",
>    data:{email_data:email_data},
>    beforeSend:function(){
>     $('#'+id).html('Sending...');
>     $('#'+id).addClass('btn-danger');
>    },
>    success:function(data){
>     if(data = 'ok')
>     {
>      $('#'+id).text('Success');
>      $('#'+id).removeClass('btn-danger');
>      $('#'+id).removeClass('btn-info');
>      $('#'+id).addClass('btn-success');
>     }
>     else
>     {
>      $('#'+id).text(data);
>     }
>     $('#'+id).attr('disabled', false);
>    }
>
>   });
>  });
> });
> ```

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Is the question actually: _"How to make an ajax request on button click in angular"_? If yes, then you should update your question to make that clear (and probably remove any PHP and PHPMailer reference, since that's irrelevant to the actual issue). If no, then the question is very much unclear.

Comment: Yes it is, but was hoping for someone from the PHPMailer community to be able to help. Someone may have done exactly the same as myself.
I shall however remove for now :)

Comment: Since the question isn't about PHPMailer but about angular, you should only include that part. When you get that working and find yourself having issues with the PHP and PHPMailer part, then you should post a separate questions about them. It's important to keep the questions as minimal and to the point as possible.

Comment: Good shout, thanks Magnus.
Whilst you are here, any idea on the above?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm better at PHP than angular.

Answer (score 0):

Here You Send Parameter and in function you not received

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm email_button" ng-click="sendData(data.customer_name)">Send Single</button>
```

the workaround

```
$scope.sendData = function sendData(para){
```

Comment: Hi Shokry, thanks for the help
Still not working, so I have posted all the code into PasteBin
https://pastebin.com/g2c8SQ6p
Sorry I am very new to Ajax and PHP

Comment: check you xhr in browser , i want know what's error ?

Answer (score 0):

In Angualr Js you should pass the parameter to the PHP script.
I guess you are not passing the value to PHP.

```
var Indata = {param:'val1',.....}
$scope.sendData = function sendData(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to send?"))
    {
        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:"send_mail.php",
            params: Indata
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.success = true;
            $scope.successMessage = data.message;
            $scope.fetchData();
        }); 
    }
}
```

Try this method,

if you face still issue i think it's better if you share your PHP code here.....

Comment: Hi Sivaprakash,
Just tried your solution, unfortunately now just coing up with {{successmessage}} and will not show any of the data from the Database.
See I originally had it working, but was a weird format in my eyes.
Ill paste it into the current issue post.

Comment: Seems still params not added inside the http request and next to the url secition.

Make sure whether the PHP file path is correct or not.